# Linking Error in Sun Studio 10 under Solaris

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, solaris, sunstudio

I wrote a test program like this:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
int main( void ) {
    int  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

And tried to compile it:

```
$ /tool/sunstudio/bin/cc test.c
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
socket                              test.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out
```

The output is "symbol socket is not referenced".

Kindly give me the direction so that I can resolve this.

Comment: fatal: Symbol referencing errors.

Comment: *"symbol socket is not referenced"* is not the error message shown above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the question.

I wrote a test program like this:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
int main( void ) {
    int  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

And tried to compile it so (this is the output that really helps, you have to remember that modern compilers really try their best to help you fix any problems):

```
$ /tool/sunstudio/bin/cc test.c
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
socket                              test.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out
```

Now, from the output we can see that the symbol `socket` is not referenced. So if you type `man socket` you will get the following from the man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
     cc [ flag ... ] file ... -lsocket  -lnsl  [ library ... ]
```

The `-l` flag indicates that to use this function you need to also link the named library. In this case you are being told to add `-lsocket -lnsl` to the `cc` command line as follows:

```
$ /tool/sunstudio/bin/cc test.c -lsocket -lnsl
```

Comment: @PP, first of all I apologize about my question.. I didn't get your point.. Please explain.

Comment: He means you should have supplied more information: in particular, the error message that you're getting from the linker. He's also suggesting you provide a complete compilable example for us to reproduce with, but I'm not sure if that's always necessary.

Comment: @Arman, apologies, I do come across harsh sometimes. It was, specifically, the linker error I was looking for. You were lucky in that your problem is a common one and most of us can determine the solution straight away. But 9 times out of 10 this is not the case - and it is the specific error returned by the program in question that will help others solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks PP.. I have got it.. And I will concentrate on my question next time.

Comment: @Arman, if you update your question with the linker error you were getting, I'll remove the downvote and upvote your question.

Answer (score 2):

you have to link in the socket library, in the command line:

```
-lsocket
```

Comment: kindly give me some explanation.

Comment: The Ide you're using (SunStudio) when it compiles uses options you provide in the project settings or makefile. Those options must include all the libraries your program needs; libraries have to be linked (statically or dynamically) to your final executable program. To link socket library, the option is the above -lsocket.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add at least `-lsocket` to your link-step, i.e. link against libsocket.so. I don't know how to do that in the SunStudio UI, though - are its projects makefile based?

The man page is usually a good place to look for required libraries; in this case the [man page for socket](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5170/socket-3socket.html#scrolltoc) also recommends `-lnsl` (see the synopsis) so that might be required too but I don't remember it being necessary.